# Private abstract declaration in traits gives static context error

Tags: groovy, abstract, traits, access-modifiers

I can't make sense of the error generated by the following code segment:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
@CompileStatic
trait FooTrait {
    void foo() {
        bar()
    }
    private abstract void bar() // private access modifier causes error
}
```

The following compiler error is generated when the `private` access modifier is used:

```
[Static type checking] - Non static method FooTrait$Trait$Helper#bar 
    cannot be called from static context
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a current limitation [as described here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7191)

> This issue is specific to `@CompileStatic`.
>
> Let me explain.
>
> When you define a static method in a trait, the static method does not "belong" to the trait. Instead, it will be copied to the class implementing the trait. So on the trait itself, the static `someStaticMethod` is not defined. For this to work, you have to know the class that will be implementing the trait, like you would for a normal static method call:
>
> ```
> SomeClassImplementingTrait.someStaticMethod() // here, someStaticMethod is defined
> ```
>
> There is no simple way to fix this without leveraging dynamic calls for any method call on "this" inside a trait, static or not.

Comment: There's no static method in the class, What we have is a private abstract method. So what you're referring to is a different issue, unless I'm missing something.